# General Practice doctors and the law on reporting colleagues

Tags: united-kingdom, medical, professional-ethics

In the UK, if one GP believes another GP has acted in a dishonest manner in their actions, for example by providing a diagnosis that is known to be false, does the first GP have a legal duty to report the second GP to the appropriate authorities?

Comment: I edited out "moral duty" since that is off-topic here. Feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see the General Medical Council's Ethical Guidance for Doctors:

> [Here](https://www.gmc-uk.org/ethical-guidance/ethical-guidance-for-doctors/raising-and-acting-on-concerns):
>
> You must take prompt action if you think patient safety, dignity or comfort is being compromised.

> [And here](https://www.gmc-uk.org/ethical-guidance/ethical-guidance-for-doctors/raising-and-acting-on-concerns/part-1-raising-a-concern#paragraph-7):
>
> All doctors have a duty to raise concerns where they believe that patient safety or care is being compromised by the practice of colleagues or the systems, policies and procedures in the organisations in which they work. They must also encourage and support a culture in which staff can raise concerns openly and safely.

Whether any criminal, civil or disciplinary action is taken will depend on the particular circumstances and available facts.